# Assign serial number to USB device

Tags: usb

I have 2 identical USB devices (Zoom F8 multitrack field recorders) which connect as a standard audio interface. I'd like to create an aggregate device using both devices. macOS definitely "sees" both devices:

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType
... 
F Series Audio Interface with Rec:

Product ID: 0x0395
Vendor ID: 0x1686  (ZOOM Corporation)
Version: 0.00
Serial Number: 000000000000
Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
Manufacturer: ZOOM Corporation
Location ID: 0x14200000 / 28
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA): 0
Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

F Series Audio Interface with Rec:

Product ID: 0x0395
Vendor ID: 0x1686  (ZOOM Corporation)
Version: 0.00
Serial Number: 000000000000
Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
Manufacturer: ZOOM Corporation
Location ID: 0x14100000 / 27
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA): 0
Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

However, only one device appears in Audio MIDI setup. I'm guessing the issue is due to the null serial numbers, and so would like to manually assign them. Of course, I wouldn't expect this to persist the devices being disconnected/reconnected.

Comment: Did you find a way to see both?  I also have two Zoom F8 recorders and have same problem on MacOS Catalina.  However, I can see them both and was able to create an aggregate device in Audio MIDI Setup if I put one in "Audio Interface" mode and the other in "Audio Interface with Rec" mode.  Using the system_profiler command you mentioned, they appear as "F Series Audio Interface with Rec" with Product ID: 0x0395, and "H and F Series Multi Track Usb Audio" with Product ID: 0x02a5.  They still both show all zeros for serial number though.